# How do I count prices of products with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, count

I made a site for school: https://preview.c9users.io/tobiasleys/periode8/order/order.html . It's about ordering burgers. All the burgers have different prices. When you select two types of burgers I want to count the prizes together and show it on the page. I linked a database called firebase. When you order a burger i can see it so that works. But how do i count the prices?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have given us much to go on but here's a rough idea based on your question

```
/* Burger Object */
function Burger(price)
{
    this.price = price;
}
/* Array of Burgers */
a = [
    Burger(4),
    Burger(4.5),
    Burger(1)
]
/* Placeholder for total cost of Burgers */
total = 0;
/* Iterate over the Burgers array adding each Burger's price to the total */
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    total += a[i].price;
/* Shout out the price! */
alert(total);
```

Comment: Do I need to put it in the .js file? And what do i need to add in my html then?

Comment: You have a couple of options. You could store the code in a js file and reference the file in your html `<script src="FILE_PATH"></script>` or you can use inline script in your html file. `<script>someCode();</script>`